# Text adventure app for Android - how to draw different content of XML layout depending on the an integer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-activity

If you don't want to go through a bit of wall of text, go to tl;dr.

I want to create a text adventure app for Android.

It's gonna be huge, so I figured out instead of creating 10,000 activities I would just work on one activity and draw different content -AND- different buttons depending on the 'page' the user is on right now.

I.e.

We start with page 0.

It shows us something like:

Page 0

Welcome Adventurer!
What gender are you?

[button 1 = string "male"
go to page 1
redraw the Activity]
[button 2 = string "female"
go to page 2
redraw the Activity]

page 1

Welcome my lady!

[button 1 = string "hello"
go to page 3
redraw the Activity]
[button 2 = string "bye"
go to page 4
redraw the Activity]

Welcome good sir!

page 2
[button 1 = string "hello"
go to page 5
redraw the Activity]
[button 2 = string "bye"
go to page 6
redraw the Activity]

As you can see it's getting complicated real quick. This is just an example of how i want it to work, the in-game choices will be a "bit" more general than 'hello' or 'bye'.

I need a way of redrawing both TextView's content AND buttons displayed under, and also some variables like 'health' or 'gold' at the very top of the screen.
All after variable 'page' is modified.

The other option is to create a different activity for each choice. Probably passing variables 'health' and 'gold' would be easy, redrawing would happen onCreate and the string's would already be in place at the new activity's XML layout.

But im not sure if i want to go through the process of creating 10,000 activites and coding in the passing of variables between the linked ones. :/

Any suggestions?

**TL;DR**
Can I redraw content of android application dependant on an integer number while staying at the same Activity all the time?

**This is similiar to what I want to achieve:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wizardsChoiceV1.toucher&hl=en**

**EDIT**
What i got now gives me no errors but it won't switch the screens. :/

```
    package com.example.textadventure;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public static int page = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        onClick(view);
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        break;
        case R.id.button2:
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        break;
        default:
            //code..
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you don't want to create an activity for each choice. You probably want to split your design into components and create a layout for each one that differs significantly.

Then you can create a layout that composes these components together depending on the current state of the game, and also defines the values associated with the individual views in the layouts.

For example, you might have a component to represent the status of your character (health, gold, equipment etc) and several components representing different types of choices (description with yes/no choice, room with description, some interactive items/object and some exits).

You would keep your game state stored somewhere in your activity and based on that state decide which components are needed, for example, if you're at the starting location with a fresh character you might show the character status layout at the top and a room layout at the bottom.

The character status layout would contain a number of View objects which you can modify to match the current character state, and likewise for the room layout.

Comment: This is similiar to what i want to achieve:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wizardsChoiceV1.toucher&hl=en

Comment: `setContentView()` can be used to change the layout in an Activity, but that is only one piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I guess I have to use a listener and somehow do a switch for each ID. How is the question? Gonna do research.